# Usar una variable como nombre de fichero?

Tags: android

Necesito crear un archivo XML cuyo nombre sea el título y la fecha cuando fue creado, para diferenciarse de los demás XML.El problema es que cuando intento crear el fichero se lanza una excepción si el nombre de este tiene involucrada una variable:

```
File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(),"prueba.xml");
dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Esto lo crea sin problemas, en cambio si fuera así

```
File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(),momento+"prueba.xml");
dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

Siendo momento un String donde guardo la fecha, pone que no se encuentra el fichero y lanza excepción, alguno me puede iluminar?

Variable momento:

```
    calendario= Calendar.getInstance();
    hora=calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minutos=calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    segundos=calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    año=calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes=calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    dia=calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    momento=dia+"/"+mes+"/"+año+" - "+hora+":"+minutos+":"+segundos;
```

Esto último dentro de onCreate()

Comment: ¿Puedes poner como asignas la variable momento?

Comment: Listo @MiguelMartinez

Comment: No puedes usar dos puntos `:` en los nombres de un fichero

Comment: Tal y como te dice Pablo Lozano, los dos puntos son los que te están dando el problema. Un archivo no puede tener ese caracter en el nombre.

Comment: Hola @AngelGonzalezPena y cual es el error, debes ser especifico, revisar [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si al agregar la variable momento como prefijo de tu archivo obtienes el problema, significa que el problema se debe a esta variable.

En realidad la variable momento obtendría un valor como ejemplo: "5/12/2017 - 10:10:10", si agregas este valor como prefijo a tu nombre de archivo, estarías intentando crear un archivo:

```
/storage/emulated/0/5/12/2017 - 10:10:10prueba.xml
```

**En realidad el problema es la nomenclatura que agregas como prefijo a tu archivo, no es aceptada por el sistema de archivos, principalmente por el uso del símbolo `:`, por lo tanto te sugiero cambiar el formato**, ejemplos:

```
yyyyMMdd_hhmmss
yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss
```

Si usas `yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss` como prefijo, lo crearías de esta forma:

```
 String momento = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia+" "+hora+"-"+minutos+"-"+segundos;

 File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File f = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), momento + "prueba.xml");
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
```

y no tendrías problema para crear tu archivo con el prefijo de fecha/hora.

---

Las utilidades del sistema de archivos y las convenciones de nombres en Windows prohíben que ciertos caracteres aparezcan en los nombres de archivos, revisa esta tabla (los últimos dos son "permitidos", pero con ciertas restricciones).:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Independientemente del lenguaje utilizado, si intentas guardar un archivo con dos puntos (`:`) te dará una excepción puesto que es un carácter especial no permitido.

Hay varios caracteres que no están permitidos en el nombre de un archivo y son los siguientes:

```
\ / : * ? " < > |
```

Si sustituyes los dos puntos por una barra baja (`_`) u otro carácter que no esté entre los que te he indicado arriba te funcionará.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en que quizás el Date de "momento" tiene espacios o algo por el estilo, no sé si en Android el la clase `File` , crea propiamente el archivo en local, mira si existe una clase en Android similar a `FileWriter` que esta con solo poner la ruta y el nombre con la variable, la crea sin problemas.
Espero haberte podido ayudar.

```
public void crearArchivo(){
        Date momento = new Date();
        FileWriter f = null;
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        String momentostr = ft.format(momento);
        String filename = momentostr+"prueba.xml";
        try{
            f = new FileWriter(filename);
            f.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quiero dar mi respuesta y argumentar que la misma complementa varias de las respuestas ya descritas. 
Resolviendo el tema del nombre del fichero o carpeta (que no puede contener caracteres especiales), porque no intentas validar la existencia del fichero y si no existe crealo.
Algo como lo siguiente:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourDirectoryName");//variable momento en un formato correcto
boolean success = true;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
}
if (success) {
    // Codigo para crear archivo 
} else {
    // Algo sucedió mal... 
}
```

De esta manera creas el fichero, necesitas tomar el path de este fichero:
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + momento; //esto es el path`

Esto es una alternativa y complementa las respuestas de los demás. Igualmente recuerda si te fue de ayuda dale hacia arriba!!!